# How do you state multiple comparisons in one sentence?

Tags: comparisons

> The topics covered range from the homeless to celebrities, from
> ghettos to gated communities and from white to black.

In the sentence above, do I need to include "from" all 3 times or do I just need it once at the beginning like so?:

> The topics covered range from the homeless to celebrities,
> ghettos to gated communities and white to black.

Comment: Both are grammatical. Which you pick depends on considerations of style, emphasis, flow, etc.

Comment: @Lawrence Would you choose one or the other depending on medium? For example, would the latter be more appropriate for a CV or poster and would the former be better for a paper?

Comment: The *from* helps separate the three pairs, because it's not A to B to C ...

Comment: @Mitty The medium (and maybe even register) doesn't matter - it's a choice of the effect you're trying to create. The "from ... from ... from" phrasing can be grander; the other form showcases more of the content. Sometimes you want your beef in a pie; other times, you want steak on its own. (Or mushroom, if you're vegetarian.)

Comment: @Lawrence If you want to supply an answer, I can then then mark it as the solution and give you credit. Thanks

Comment: Please cite, attribute and link sources. [SSC CGL Preparatory Guide ... ](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/SSC_CGL_Preparatory_Guide/SfcwDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22time+we+had+begun%22&pg=PT19&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are grammatical, and neither stands out as a higher or lower register. However, the repeated *from ... from ... from ...* phrasing is more dramatic whereas the more compact form showcases the content. Sometimes, you want your beef in a pie; other times, you want steak on its own. Or mushroom, if you're vegetarian. :)